# Can a Ranger who took God Amidst The Wastes take advanced Cleric moves?

Tags: cleric, dungeon-world, ranger

Can a Ranger who took God Amidst The Wastes take advanced Cleric moves?

By the direct reading of the move it would seem that it's limited only to commune and cast a spell moves, but I am not completely sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The move is very explicit: the Ranger gets only those two Cleric moves.

Answer (score 9):

## You can't advance as a Cleric, but...

A Ranger who takes God Amidst the Wastes is still limited to selecting from Ranger moves as they level up. The text

> Every time you gain a level thereafter, increase your effective cleric level by 1.

refers only to boosting the level-based cap on spells you can prepare when you Commune.

The Ranger also has pretty much no access to moves which could let them multiclass, and therefore take advantage of the Cleric spells. Advanced Cleric Moves like Invigorate, Serenity, or Empower all depend on Cleric spells being there to begin with.

There are, however, two options.

### Option 1: Beg

I mean, that's just the rules, right? If you're really playing this "servant of a wilderness god" thing to the hilt, your GM might be fine with you taking Cleric moves anyway as you level up, instead of Ranger ones. Breaking the rules to suit the campaign you've got going on is just part of the job.

But it **is** breaking the rules, so y'know. Don't depend on it, use at your own risk.

### Option 2: Spirit Animal

The Ranger does have a 6-10 move called Special Trick.

> Choose a move from another class. So long as you are working with your animal companion you have access to that move.

And pointing that at a Cleric advanced move might seem a little weird? But if you **are** playing into the "servant of a wilderness god" thing, it wouldn't be that odd for your animal companion to have some effects on your cleric spells.

Answer (score 4):

**Level Up** is a Move. In the Dungeon World context, Moves are just a rule with a trigger.

> When you have downtime (hours or days) and XP equal to (or greater than) your current level+7, you can reflect on your experiences and hone your skills.
>
> - Subtract your current level+7 from your XP.
> - Increase your level by 1.
> - Choose a new advanced move *from your class*.
> - If you are the wizard, you also get to add a new spell to your spellbook.
> - Choose one of your stats and increase it by 1 (this may change your modifier). > Changing your Constitution increases your maximum and current HP. Ability scores can’t go higher than 18.

As you can see, you can only select new moves from your class. Since **God Amidst the Wastes** doesn't change your class, you can't take advanced moves from that class when you level up. Bard, Cleric, and Fighter provide the **Multiclass Initiate** and **Multiclass Dabbler** moves, which would allow you take a prerequisite ability and then a subsequent ability but even they don't fully unlock the playbook. The only way to do this is to take the **Beyond 10th Level** option *Change entirely to a new class*.

Answer (score 1):

## The concept of the servant of a wilderness god

The move itself doesn't allow you to further enhance your "cleric" spellcasting abilities or get other advanced moves from the cleric class, but if the concept of the servant of some sort of god is becoming a core concept, maybe talking to your GM about getting a corresponding **compendium class** would be a good move.
I don't know if there is any cc fitting your needs, but you could work with your GM on making one that fits your concept and maybe even an event that already happened in your game as the trigger for the compendium class

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.